# ext4 partition is broken during resizing with gparted

Tags: fedora, ext4, data-recovery, gparted, parted

I installed Fedora 28. But I resized the partition that contained Fedora (/dev/sda7) wrongly using GParted and now I can't boot my system. (Note the partition format is ext4)

Comment: Boot a live cd and see if you can repair the partition with fsck

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing a partition does not implicitly resize any filesystem it might contain. You should have shrunk the filesystem and *then* shrunk the partition. (I'm surprised `gparted` didn't warn you.)

However, to try and fix the damage, resize the partition back to whatever it was before. If you're not sure of the value then make sure it's *at least* the size it was before.

If you have already used the space then all bets are off, unfortunately. You might get some of your files back with a filesystem rescue tool. Or you might not.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Now I can use my OS. Thank you very much. **:)**